# pass Id in onclick to js controller

Tags: lightning-events, onclick, lighting-web-component

I'm trying to write my own version of pills in LWC without using the base component. I want to be able to pass the item.Id once a pill is clicked, but I always get undefined.

HTML:

```
    <template for:each={items} for:item="item">
        <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link" key={item.Id} onclick={addToTable}>
            <span class="slds-pill__action">
                <span class="slds-pill__label">{item.label}</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS Controller:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Basic extends LightningElement {
    addToTable(event){
        console.log(event.target.dataset.id); //output: undefined
        console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.id); //output: undefined
    }    
    items = [
        {
...
...
```

You can play with the code [here](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/QBOz5kKK3s9zuMvFgaJr/), what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataset` only works when you have attribute like this `data-id` in your html.

```
<template>
    <template for:each={items} for:item="item">
        <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link color" data-id={item.id} key={item.id} onclick={addToTable}>
            <span class="slds-pill__action" title="Full pill label verbiage mirrored here" >
                <span class="slds-pill__label">{item.label}</span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </template>
</template>
```

I modified your code to add a [data-set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute and it worked fine.

https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/AvOakWCJ0VREifiuixeL/src/basic.js?p=stories